# Clear the label before calling a JavaScript function which displays timer through the same function [Session Timeout]

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, countdowntimer, session-timeout, timertask

I tried to display timer on webpage in label (label id is MsgTimer) using following function. But when the function is called the 2/more times then 2/ more timers are displayed and it won't reset the timer but overload the label text and display multiple timers on a lable. I want to reset the label text each time the function is called.

```
function startTimer() {
    var x;
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("MsgTimer").innerHTML = "";
    // Here I was supposed to fetch the SessionTimeout data from appsettings.json 
    // But for now I entered data manually for 15 minutes
    var countDownDate = new Date().getTime() + 900000;
    // Update the count down every 1 second              
    x = setInterval(function () {        
        // Get todays date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        // Find the distance between now and the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;
        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var hours = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        // add a zero in front of numbers<10
        function checkTime(i) {
            if (i < 10) {
                i = "0" + i;
            }
            return i;
        }
        hours = checkTime(hours);
        minutes = checkTime(minutes);
        seconds = checkTime(seconds);


        // Display the result in the element with id="lblTime"
        document.getElementById("MsgTimer").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("MsgTimer").innerHTML = "Session Expires In" + " " + minutes + " : " + seconds + "";

        // If the count down is finished, write some text
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("MsgTimer").innerHTML = "SESSION EXPIRED";
            window.alert("Session Timeout");
        }                     
    }, 1000);
}
startTimer();
```

Comment: Where is `x` defined, and where is `clearInterval` defined?

Comment: `x` is defined on 5th line and assigned a function `setInterval` on 7th line and `clearInterval` is inbuilt function of javascript which should clear the `SetInterval` data.

Comment: `x` is defined after it's being passed in to `clearInterval(x)`

Comment: Thank You for responding, I just tried your suggestion but won't resolve my problem. Appreciate your help.

Comment: This might help https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Comment: I am on in. tysm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code might be the `var x;` declaration, because variables declared using `var` keywords, are actually function scoped.

So, every time `startTimer();` is called it is creating a new `x` variable within the function scope only and because of that the `clearInterval(x)` cannot clear the previous interval because it cannot access the previous value of `x` from previous `startTimer();` call.

Try moving your `var x;` declaration outside the function and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Updated [Working]:

```
/* Timer - Display Session Timeout */
var x = 0;
function startTimer() {        
    var countDownDate = (new Date().getTime()) + ((parseInt(@SessionTimer)) * 60000);
    clearInterval(x);
    x = setInterval(function () {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = countDownDate - now;
        var hours = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        function checkTime(i) {
            if (i < 10) {
                i = "0" + i;
            }
            return i;
        }
        hours = checkTime(hours);
        minutes = checkTime(minutes);
        seconds = checkTime(seconds);
        document.getElementById("MsgTimer").innerHTML = "Session Expires In" + " " + hours + " : " + minutes + " : " + seconds + "";
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("MsgTimer").innerHTML = "SESSION EXPIRED";
            window.alert("Session Timeout");
        }
    }, 1000);
}
startTimer();
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative [JQuery]:

```
/* Show 15 Minutes Timer */
var timer2 = "15:01";
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    var timer = timer2.split(':');
    //by parsing integer, I avoid all extra string processing
    var minutes = parseInt(timer[0], 10);
    var seconds = parseInt(timer[1], 10);
    --seconds;
    minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;
    if (minutes < 0) clearInterval(interval);
    seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
    seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
    //minutes = (minutes < 10) ?  minutes : minutes;
    $('.countdown').html('Session Expires In' + ' ' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
    timer2 = minutes + ':' + seconds;
}, 1000);
```